# How to "test -f" with wildcard in path?

Tags: bash

How can I see if a file exists using `test -f` and with a wildcard in the path?

This works:

```
test -f $PREFIX/lib/python3.6/some_file
```

This does not work (what am I doing wrong here?):

```
test -f $PREFIX/lib/python*/some_file
```

I need a non-zero exit code if the file does not exist.

Comment: When you say "this does not work" do you mean an error ocurs or it returns false when you were expecting true?

Comment: You might be interested in the `failglob` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand wildcard to an array and then check first element:

```
f=($PREFIX/lib/python*/some_file)
if [[ -f "${f[0]}" ]]; then echo "found"; else echo "not found"; fi
unset f
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the files as `test -f` only works with a single file. I would use a shell function for that:

```
#!/bin/sh
# test-f.sh

test_f() {
    for fname; do
        if test -f "$fname"; then
            return 0
        fi
    done
}

test_f "$@"
```

Then a test run could be

```
$ sh -x test-f.sh
$ sh -x test-f.sh doesnotexist*
$ sh -x test-f.sh *
```

Comment: @user3439894 Obiously. Thanks for noticing and reporting. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

From the man page of `test`:

`-f file       True if file exists and is a regular file`

meaning that `test -f <arg>` expects `arg` to be a **single** file. If your wildcard in path results in multiple files an error will be thrown.

Try iterating when using a wildcard :)